# Regular expression for Number with a hyphen and a decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

Can I have a regular expression for validate below mentioned type number in javascript and ExtJS.

```
555-56866.9
```

I tried this `/^[0-9]+(-?[0-9])?(.?[0-9])?/g` but it didn't work exactly the way I want.

Comment: this http://regex101.com/r/qY7jA2 regular expression ^[\d]{3}-[\d]{5}.[\d]$

Comment: How did your attempt differ from what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your RegEx pattern as a basis:

`/^[0-9]+(-?[0-9])?(.?[0-9])?/g`

Replace digit character-group with shortcut:

`/^\d+(-?\d)?(.?\d)?/g`

Fix the pattern so it supports multiple digits in different places:

`/^\d+(-?\d+)?(.?\d+)?/g`

Correctly escape the dot and make it match start to end:

`/^\d+(-?\d+)?(\.?\d+)?$/g`

Done. Check it here: http://regex101.com/r/zS1tC8

Comment: Great..This works perfectly what i want..thanks @S.B., only the correction for one decimal place /^\d+(-?\d+)?(\.?\d)?$/g..Thank you again..Best answer..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always want to match three digits followed by a dash followed by five digits followed by a period followed by a single digit, this should do it:

```
^\d{3}\-\d{5}\.\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[\d]*-?[\d]*.?[\d]*$
```

I assumed that you want - and . as optional.

If you want these symbols as mendetory then try

```
 ^[\d]*-[\d]*.[\d]*$
```

Hope this will help you..!! :)

Comment: Why are you using character class?

Comment: What you mean by that ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: `\d` is sufficient as it's the same than `[\d]`. Moreover you have to escape the dot ie.: `\.`; your first regex matches empty string; the second matches `-x`.

Comment: @rzshss You can mark this as an answer if this is what you need. So that if someone see this question, he can find answer, too.

Comment: I know it but i can't do that cause i'm out of reputations to do it. Sorry for that..